# Replace consecutive occurrences of a particular number in the sequence with a single occurrence of it

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I am not able to sort out this particular problem.
Given the sequence:

```
1  1  2  2  3  3  4  1  1  5  6  7  1  1
```

I want consecutive occurrence of 1's to be replaced by a single occurrence of 1.

```
1  2  2  3  3  4  1  5  6  7  1
```

I tried using [DistinctUntilChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229508(v=vs.103)) but that did not work.

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1 };
            IObservable<int> intObsrvr = intList.ToObservable();
            intObsrvr
                .DistinctUntilChanged(x => x == 1)
                .SubscribeConsole();
```

Output I got was:

```
1,2,1,5,1
```

I am also curious about how does this keySelector thing works as I cannot explain the output sequence I have got here.

Comment: Is it necessary to use .reactive? As using Linq is pretty easy enough.

Comment: @MatrixTai - How would you do it using plain Linq? Keeping in mind that `IObservable<T>` uses Linq just as much as `IEnumerable<T>` does - as far as the language is concerned they share the same syntax.

Comment: @Enigmativity , I am not familiar with `.reactive` so they may be just the same. I post an answer for using simply `.linq`.

Comment: @MatrixTai The input sequence is actually an IObservable source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var intList = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1 };
var intObsrvr = intList.ToObservable();

var query =
    intObsrvr
        .Scan(
            new { skip = false, value = int.MinValue },
            (a, x) =>  new { skip = (a.value == 1) && (x == 1) , value = x })
        .Where(x => !x.skip)
        .Select(x => x.value);
```

I feel that `.Scan` is very undervalued.

---

You can also use `.Publish`/`Zip`/`SelectMany`:

```
var query =
    intObsrvr.Publish(
        xs => xs
            .StartWith(int.MinValue)
            .Zip(xs, (z, x) => z == 1 & x == 1 ? new int[] { } : new [] { x })
            .SelectMany(x => x));
```

Take your pick.

---

```
var query =
    intObsrvr.Publish(
        xs => xs
            .StartWith(int.MinValue)
            .Zip(xs, (z, x) => z == 1 & x == 1
                ? Observable.Empty<int>()
                : Observable.Return(x))
            .SelectMany(x => x));
```

Even more options.

Comment: Yeah. This one works. Thanks!! Any ideas why DistinctUntilChanged was giving that weird result? An why simple operations turn out to be a bit on the complicated side with Reactive !!!!

Comment: @NotAgain - `.DistinctUntilChanged(x => x == 1)` didn't work because it was just giving you the first number after a `1` and the first `1` after any other number.

Comment: @NotAgain - It certainly is true that Rx can be more complex - do keep in mind that you're working with collections that include a time component. It's a little like time travel - things get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Another `Zip` variant without `SelectMany`:

```
var observable = new List<int> { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1 }
    .ToObservable();

observable.StartWith(int.MinValue).Zip(observable, (previous, current) => (previous, current))
    .Where(t => t.current != 1 || t.current != t.previous)
    .Select(t => t.current);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own method if inbuilt ones don't match your requirements.

A `DistinctUntilChanged` that meets your needs is rather straightforward:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctUntilChanged<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source) 
{
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!e.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        yield return e.Current;
        var previous = e.Current;

        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!e.Current.Equals(previous))
            {
                yield return e.Current;
                previous = e.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the OP is looking for an Rx solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation:

```
/// <summary>Replaces repeated contiguous occurrences of a specific value
/// with a single occurrence of this value.</summary>
public static IObservable<TSource> DistinctUntilChanged<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source, TSource value)
{
    var comparer = EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
    return source
        .Select((v, i) => (Value: v, Index: i))
        .DistinctUntilChanged(e => comparer.Equals(e.Value, value) ? -1 : e.Index)
        .Select(entry => entry.Value);
}
```

This implementation  assumes that the sequence has less than 2,147,483,647 elements, otherwise it will fail with an `OverflowException`. That's because it compares the indices instead of the values, and the type of the index is `Int32`.